# ESP-01 module CH_EN pin confusion

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a custom board that I have developed where I am using the ESP-01 module.

[image: ESP-01 Pin Out]

I have not connected the CH_EN pin to GND or Vcc on the board. When I connect the module to the board, the red LED lights up, but the code doesn't work. When I tried to short CH_PD and Vcc pins so as to pull the CH_EN pin high, the red light started blinking very weakly and it still didn't do what it was supposed to do.

Is the CH_EN pin supposed to be pulled up or pulled down all the time?
Does the onboard red LED's blinking mean my power supply has an issue?

Please help.

Comment: I've not needed to wire the CH_EN pin on my esp01s. I'd suggest you check your power supply. The esp is very picky - you need to ensure you have enough current available otherwise it will get upset.

Comment: @Kartman, esp-01S has on board pull-up for CH-PD. normal esp-01 doesn't. CH-PD is "enable" pin. it should be pulled up for esp8266 to work.

Comment: @Juraj so I think in this case, my ESP-01 doesnt have CH-PD pulled high. But when I do short it with the 3.3v pin, the red led onboard the ESP board starts kind of breathing / weakly blinking. Does it have to do with power supply then? My schematic - 

https://imgur.com/Eof2UHv

Comment: The schematic is near unreadable both in reproduction and layout. From what I can interpret, it does look suspect.

Comment: @Kartman its basically a 5V 200ma design based on MP150GJ-Z and then AM117-3.3V.

Comment: ‘Basically’ suggests you don’t fully realise the complexity of the circuit. Layout and component selection is critical. There’s nothing basic about it.

Comment: @Kartman I am beginner I understand I may have screwed up somewhere but I used the reference design from the MP150GJ datasheet. Is 200 ma enough for the ESP module?

Comment: Rather than rely on guesses and opinions, seek hard evidence. How much current is required? Refer to the Espressif documentation. 
Is your power supply a problem? Test your board with a known good power supply. 

Especially with switchedmode power supplies, the schematic only tells half the story. The other half is the circuit layout - track width, length etc and component choice. One 10uF 10V capacitor is not necessarily the same as another. If you go to Digikey, Mouser or Lcsc there’s a zillion caps with the same 10uF 10V spec. Which one to choose?

Comment: As per i know, I have always put the pin to the vcc and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Old post but no one mentions the reset pin which on the esp-01 also must be pulled up. Indeed on the esp-01s both reset en ch_pd have internal pullups.